# Ms Access Report Layout

Tags: ms-access, layout, report, grouping

I am trying to design report layout as shown in the image below. Can anyone guide me in general steps how can I make it possible?

[image: Report layout]

Comment: Hi givanse, thanks for replying to me. I have designed table with datas: Name, Item, Price1, Price 2. I designed report based on this table. So while are many names same, i grouped them. I am looking for different layout of grouping (i am looking for grouping like one in image described in my question). Here you have another link which tells you what i am getting when i apply grouping. LINK: http://oi61.tinypic.com/1z4kb47.jpg
Thanks for your time!
Rimra

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you want to do everything in a single table. It will be easier if you design it with three tables, maybe more, it all depends on your constrains.

For example, you could use one big table that contains the other two. Something like this:

```
 ----------------------------
|        | Outer table       |
|--------|-------------------|
|group 1 |  ---------------  |
|        | | Inner table 1 | |
|        |  ---------------  |
|----------------------------|
|group 2 |  ---------------  |
|        | | Inner table 2 | |
|        |  ---------------  |
 ----------------------------
```

Comment: Givanse, actually i have designed two tables. And they are in relation as you wrote in your comment. I created report based on table and grouped with ID, i put ID also in Detail Section page of Report. In ID field in properties, i make NO DUPLICATES, so now i have Just one ID value and its good. Now i have one more step to solve my problem. I need to shrink ID field, based on how many rows are in that group. how to make it dynamically based on numbers of rows of items. http://s2.postimg.org/kcpsnvx49/1658704_10203169386458467_1341206980_o.jpg